# Does Files.createTempDirectory remove the directory after JVM exits normally?

Tags: java

Does `Files.createTempDirectory` remove the directory after JVM exits normally? Or do I need to manually recursively remove the temporary directory content?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As per [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29), no it doesn't, you need to manually remove the directory, using [`file.deleteOnExit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()) method.

> As with the createTempFile methods, this method is only part of a temporary-file 
>   facility. 
>   A shutdown-hook, or the File.deleteOnExit() mechanism may be used to 
>   delete the directory automatically.

Comment: Like will this work? `new File(Files.createTempDirectory(null).toString()).deleteOnExit()`

Comment: @HowardGuo, I don't think so, you are passing null to createTempDirectory method

Comment: @HowardGuo, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html this should give you more information

Comment: I thought the document says that `prefix` parameter may be given null

Comment: @HowardGuo, no it cannot be :) In the link you can refer example program

Comment: Am i missing anything here? I thought I read: `prefix - the prefix string to be used in generating the directory's name; may be null`

Comment: @HowardGuo, yes prefix maybe null, but not others. If you read API docs, this method accepts 3 arguments and your code won't compile since you are passing only 1 argument

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this piece of code: `val dir = Files.createTempDirectory(null); new File(dir.toString()).deleteOnExit()` it creates the temp directory but does not delete it after JVM exists. guess I have to find another way to delete the dir..

Comment: @PradeepSimha - what makes you say you can't pass `null`?  You certainly can call [`Files.createTempDirectory(null)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory(java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)), this works exactly as one would expect - it creates a new arbitrarily named directory and returns its Path.

Answer (score 64):

Temporary directories created by [`Files.createTempDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory%28java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29) are not deleted upon system exit (JVM termination), unless you configure them to do so:

> A [shutdown-hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29), or the [`File.deleteOnExit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29) mechanism may be used to delete the directory automatically.

Meaning you could call:

```
Path tmp = Files.createTempDirectory(null);
tmp.toFile().deleteOnExit();
```

However you cannot delete a directory unless it's empty, as document by [`File.delete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29):

> Deletes the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname. If
> this pathname denotes a directory, then the directory must be empty in
> order to be deleted.

So we need to get a bit fancier if you want the directory and its contents deleted.  You can recursively register a directory and its children for deletion like so:

```
public static void recursiveDeleteOnExit(Path path) throws IOException {
  Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
        @SuppressWarnings("unused") BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
      file.toFile().deleteOnExit();
      return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
        @SuppressWarnings("unused") BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
      dir.toFile().deleteOnExit();
      return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
  });
}
```

Take note however, this registers all *currently existing files* for deletion - if after calling this method you create new files, they and their parent directories will not be deleted per the documented behavior of `File.delete()`.

If you want to delete a directory upon exit, regardless of the contents of said directory, you can use a shutdown-hook in an almost identical manner:

```
public static void recursiveDeleteOnShutdownHook(final Path path) {
  Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(
    new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                @SuppressWarnings("unused") BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                throws IOException {
              Files.delete(file);
              return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException e)
            throws IOException {
          if (e == null) {
            Files.delete(dir);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
          }
          // directory iteration failed
          throw e;
        }
        });
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to delete "+path, e);
      }
    }}));
}
```

Note however that calling this repeatedly registers a new shutdown thread each time, which could potentially cause problems at scale.  `File.deleteOnExit()` stores a set of registered files, and deletes all of them in one shutdown hook.  If you need to delete many directories in this manner, you'd want to implement something similar.

Comment: In Spring there's a helper method
`org.springframework.util.FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(File root)`
for explicit recursive directory deletion.

Answer (score 24):

You can add apache commons io dependency to your project and then use FileUtils.deleteDirectory() to do something like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            FileUtils.deleteDirectory(tmp_dir_path.toFile());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

For more information about apache commons check:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

Comment: Worth noting that this deletes the directory, whether or not it's empty.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't - [`createTempDirectory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29)

> As with the `createTempFile` methods, this method is only part of a
>   temporary-file facility. A [shutdown-hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29), or the [`File.deleteOnExit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29)
>   mechanism may be used to delete the directory automatically.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. You have to do it on your own. Or use `java.io.File.deleteOnExit()` but I guess it doesn't work for non-empty directories

Comment: I would love Java more if `new File(Files.createTempDirectory(null).toString()).deleteOnExit()` works, hahaha..

Comment: It works exactly as documented - "the directory must be empty in order to be deleted" - wanting to delete a non-empty directory is reasonable, but don't confuse your desire with "Java doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

If using JUnit 5, the `@TempDir` annotation is super nice. It also recursively deletes the created directory when the test or test-class ends (depending on the scope of the annotation).

For example:

```
@BeforeAll
public static void setup(@TempDir Path tempDir) {
    // The dir will be deleted when the class ends, ala @AfterClass
}
```

Or

```
@Test
public static void myTest(@TempDir Path tempDir) {
    // The dir will be deleted when this test method ends
}
```

See: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-temporary-directory